# Selenium Webdriver locator for div class compound text

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am attempting to click a button that shares alot of code with other objects within the UI. Here is the code for the button:

```
<div class="ui green ok inverted button">
<i class="checkmark icon"></i> Yes </div>
```

Here is the modal the button is a part of:

```
<div class="actions">  <div class="ui red cancel inverted button">
<i class="remove icon"></i> No </div>
<div class="ui green ok inverted button">
<i class="checkmark icon"></i> Yes </div> <!--anchor--> </div>
```

Here is an example of what I have tried without success:

By.xpath("//div[text()='green']")

I have also attempted "class" tag locators and other div class text locators and I get "unable to find" every time. The text "green" and "Yes" are the only unique attributes for this particular object.

Comment: can you please share full html code for button?

Comment: The HTML above is all of the code used for the button. Here is the HTML of the modal that the button is a part of:      <div class="actions">  <div class="ui red cancel inverted button"> <i class="remove icon"></i> No </div> <div class="ui green ok inverted button"> <i class="checkmark icon"></i> Yes </div> <!--anchor--> </div>

Comment: //*[@class="checkmark icon" and text()="Yes"]  try this

Comment: This locator does not work, although it looks like it should!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='actions']//div[@class='ui green ok inverted button']")
```

Comment: Hmmm... Now I am getting "Element Not Visible" which sounds like its recognized but can't be interacted with. Seems like the locator itself is working though, so thanks!

Comment: It turns out there WAS a duplicate object in the code, which was recognizable, but set to invisible.

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[contains(@class,"green")]
```

Comment: I attempted the code above and received this error:    Error: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //div[contains(@class,'green')]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work out a CSS Selector for this as well:

*By.cssSelector(".odr-disconnect-phone .ui.green.ok.inverted.button"*